# Attempting to use FindOne mongoose method in for loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meanjs

I am attempting to use the mongoose findOne method with my user model to find a displayName if it already exists, if it does i want to change the display name and check again for its uniqueness until a unique displayname is not achieved. The code which i wrote was something like this:

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('User'),
exports.signup = function(req, res) {
delete req.body.roles;
var message = null;
// Add missing user fields
req.body.provider='local';
req.body.displayName = req.body.firstName + ' ' + req.body.lastName;

var flag=false;
for( var i=1;i>=1;i++) {
    console.log(req.body.displayName);
    if(!flag) {
        User.findOne({'displayName': req.body.displayName}, function (err, user) {
            if (user) {
                req.body.displayName = req.body.firstName + ' ' + req.body.lastName + '.' + i;
            }
            if (err) {
                flag = true;
            }
        });
    }
    else break;
}
var user = new User(req.body);
// Then save the user 
user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('failed to save user');
        });
    } else {
        // Remove sensitive data before login
        user.password = undefined;
        user.salt = undefined;
    }
 });
```

the above code was prompting an error:

```
                });
                  ^ Don't make functions within a loop.
```

How should i be using this code to generate a unique display name?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

-Parv

Comment: This will not work as expected at all as mongoose functions are asynchronous. Anyway, why do you need to this in a loop at all?

Comment: Actually i am new to MongoDB. I don't know how to achieve this functionality. So far i came up with this logic and it was not working. It will be really helpful if you suggest me a way to generate unique display name for each user.

Comment: If you could post the full code for your request handler I could help you write a working query

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the user inside the callback of the find by username function:

```
req.body.provider='local';
req.body.displayName = req.body.firstName + ' ' + req.body.lastName;

User.findOne({'displayName': req.body.displayName}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      flag = true;
    }
    if (user) {
        req.body.displayName = req.body.firstName + ' ' + req.body.lastName + '.' + i;
        return res.render('view');
    }

    user.save(function(err) {
       if (err) {
           console.log('failed to save user');
       } else {
           // Remove sensitive data before login
           user.password = undefined;
           user.salt = undefined;
       }
    });
});
```

Moreover, you have a syntax error in here:

```
    if (err) {
         console.log('failed to save user');
    }); //this line should be replaced with a single closing bracket
```